# JiraAPIとGASを利用したbasic認証をしてもレスポンスが空になっている

Tags: google-apps-script

以下は使用しているコードの一部分です。
JiraAPIを使ってbasic認証をし、JQLで一致する課題を抽出しようとしています。
APIトークンへのアクセス履歴は残っていて、JQLもJira上で使用しているものなのですが、responseが空っぽです。
何が原因なのでしょうか

```
function sendRequest(method, resource, params) {
  let url = "https://your-domain.atlassian.net" + resource;
  const account = "your-account@example.com";
  const apiToken = "your-api-token"; 
  let options = {
    "method" : method,
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(account + ":" + apiToken),
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true
  }

  if (params!=""){
    options["payload"] = JSON.stringify(params);
  }

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  const responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  const responseBody = response.getContentText();

  if ([200, 201].indexOf(responseCode)<0){
    throw new Error(responseCode + " : " + responseBody);
  }
  
  return JSON.parse(responseBody);  
}
```